# SQLite syncing to MYSQL

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I'm developing an android app. And I require my local SQLite DB to sync with MySQL DB on a wamp server. I'm trying to figure out that what's the best and standardized approach to solve the matter. I'm new on developing android so sorry if my question sounds noobish.

Answer (score 0):

geplicator is a real-time solution designed to replicate data from MySQL database to any other relational database, such as Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2 UDB and MySQL.
So search for geplicator